# Test for significant difference of count data between distributions

Tags: count-data, bioinformatics

I have distributions of counts of DNA segment lengths, and I want to check if a distribution has been significantly increased between "treatments" and across populations.

Conceptual example: There are 4 populations, A, B, C and D, and treatment 1 and 2. My questions are, have all counts been significantly increased for every population across treatment 1 and 2? Has that happened for all DNA segment lengths, or only for some in the distribution of length counts? If both C and D have increased across treatment 1 and 2, is the increase of D in treatment 2 significantly greater than the increase of C in 2?

**UPDATE**

Real issue:

I have 3 populations, Africans, Europeans, East Asians, with 5 sub-populations each. I use a tool to infer DNA segments that are identical between the populations and an ancient hominin (e.g. Neanderthal). The tool infers a number of DNA segments that are shared between the human populations and the Neanderthal, of varying length. ( The length inferred is a natural number, in base pairs). A histogram of the DNA segments by their length looks like this, with bin size of a 100 base pairs:

[image: before]

If I add another population to the dataset, the DNA segment counts are increased and the histogram looks like this:

[image: after]

Here, the population marked as "Random" on the graph is the extra population added.

I want to assess if there is any significant difference to that increase across populations and across different lengths (or bins of lengths perhaps), because this could mean that the tool is unreliable, when DNA segments of the above lengths are taken into account.

**UPDATE 2**

The ratio of count change per length bin looks like this for bins that span 100 base pairs (for ex. the first bin has all counts of DNA segments with length 1-100 bp. These graphs use the minimum value of length of the bin for the x axis):

[image: bins of 100bp]

And here it is for length bins that span 1000 base pairs:

[image: bins of 1000bp]

Comment: Are treatments 1 and 2 before and after on the same patients or compared to a third control group?

Comment: @Dave 1 and 2 are before and after

Comment: Knowing that the observations are paired is a huge deal. Next question: what are groups A, B, C, and D? To me, it sounds like you want to test the differences in reaction to a treatment between DNA segments A, B, C, etc, meaning that your groups (think of ANOVA) are the segments, not the treatment, but I might be totally wrong. (If this doesn’t make sense, I’ll clarify once I post an answer. I just need a little more detail about your problem before I can do that.)

Comment: I start to realise that I have phrased the question quite wrong compared to what I want to do and that I need to be much more specific, sorry for that.. I'm using a human population genomics tool that infers common DNA segments across individuals and populations. The inference changes (more common DNA segments are inferred) once I add any extra population to the dataset. I want to test if this affects all populations equally or that there is significant difference between populations.

Comment: I’m having some trouble following your description. Please edit your original post (more room than in a comment) to describe what’s going on (pictures can be helpful...just sayin). I need to understand it better to translate your problem into statistical language, but I can tell you what I’m thinking now. It’s called a Poisson regression. If you want to read about that to see if it fits your problem, the topic to read about is just regular ANOVA testing of the means of multiple groups, not just two groups like in two-sample t-testing. (I’ll explain why when I post a full answer.)

Comment: I have edited my question with more information, let me know if there are areas I need to be more detailed. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102175/discussion-between-dave-and-earendil).